# I am getting error : Fatal error: Call to undefined method Debugger::checkSessionKey() in F:\xampp\htdocs\cakecms\views\pages\home.ctp on line 3

Tags: cakephp

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Debugger::checkSessionKey() in F:\xampp\htdocs\cakecms\views\pages\home.ctp on line 3
in cake php .

Comment: How about showing the code that is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to call $this->Session from your home.ctp? I don't think $this->Session is available to views.

If you show your code for home.ctp we could better see what is going on.